# Creating a symbol toolbar with Angular

Tags: javascript, angular.js

I have been given a requirement to create a symbol toolbar, a toolbar where each button represents a unique symbol.

This is how the toolbar would work:

1. A user clicks inside a text field and enters data.
2. The user would then click a symbol on the toolbar and it will be appended to that specific text field.
3. The browser will put focus back on that text field.

I have created this toolbar, but I really dislike my implementation because it feels really hacky. In my implementation, I created two functions, `addSymbol` and `setLastFocused` in my controller:

```
$scope.addSymbol = function (field)
{
    if (!$scope.product[$scope.lastFocusedModelKey])
    {
        $scope.product[$scope.lastFocusedModelKey] = "";
    }

    $scope.product[$scope.lastFocusedModelKey] = $scope.product[$scope.lastFocusedModelKey] + field.symbol.SymbolCharacter;

    $('#' + $scope.lastFocusedModelKey).focus();
}

$scope.setLastFocused = function (lastFocusedModelKey)
{
    $scope.lastFocusedModelKey = lastFocusedModelKey;
}
```

`SetLastFocused` is called every time a user puts focus on a text field. I pass in a string of the field name like this:

```
<input type="text" id="Foo" name="FooName" ng-model="product.Foo" class="form-control input-xs" ng-focus="setLastFocused('Foo')">
```

`AddSymbol` accepts the button field as a parameter, and appends the symbol to the model that is bound to the text field, and then re-focuses on the text field.

I feel like this is hacky because:

1. I have to use jQuery to re-focus on the text field.
2. I'm passing in a hardcoded string representing the field name (meaning if I change the name of the field and forget to change the hardcoded string, then this symbol feature will break for that specific text field).

This works fine now with a few text fields in which the users may want to append symbols, but now I'm learning I need to add the functionality to append symbols to text fields inside a whole Angular Ui-Grid (which exists inside a separate controller). So I am realizing I need to refactor this if I want this to work with a Ui-Grid as well. I know I need to move this code to a separate service, but I would also like to make this cleaner. I'm just not really sure how.

How can I make this code follow best Angular practices?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With custom directives you could save the focus in a `$scope.focusTarget` variable and the resetting of the focus can be done with a focus broadcast that have the `instanceId` (`=focusTarget` e.g. 1, 2, ...) and the new icon class so each directive called `iconInput` will receive the broadcast and check if the passed ID is matching. If it matches it applies the focus and sets the new icon class.

The ID is generated with a counter that is incremented at every controller run of the `iconInput` directive.

Please have a look at the code below (then it's more clear how it works, it's a bit difficult to describe) or in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/d0y6gy9r/).

The first focus is only working in jsfiddle if you open the fiddle in full screen mode. Not sure what's wrong.

```js
angular.module('demoApp', [])
    .directive('iconbar', IconbarDirective)
    .directive('iconInput', IconInputDirective)
 .factory('focus', FocusFactory)
    .controller('mainController', MainController);

function IconbarDirective(focus) {
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        transclude: true,
        scope: {
            focusTarget: '@'
        },
        template: '<div class="iconbar" ng-transclude></div>',
        link: function (scope, element) {
            var icons = element.find('i');
            console.log(icons);
            icons.addClass('iconbar-icon');
            element.find('i').bind('click', function (evt) {
                console.log('clicked', evt.target, this);
                var icon = angular.element(this),
                    iconClasses = icon[0].className.split('ng-scope'), // third is ng-scope
                 target = scope.focusTarget;

                //console.log(iconClasses);
                //console.log(iconClasses[0]);
                focus('focus' + target, iconClasses[0]);
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    }
}

function IconInputDirective() {
    var instanceCounter = 0;
    return {
        restrict: 'EA',
        scope: {
            target: '='
        },
        template: '<div class="icon-input"><i class="icon-placeholder" ng-class="placeholder()"></i>' +
            '<input type="text" placeholder="enter text..."/>' +
            '</div>',
        controller: function ($scope) {
            instanceCounter++;
            this.instanceId = instanceCounter;
            console.log('instance no.', instanceCounter);
            $scope.placeholder = function() {
             return $scope.icon || 'fa fa-bars icon-invisible';
            };
        },
        link: function (scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            var inputBox = element.find('input');
            inputBox.bind('focus', function () {
                // clear other acitve classes
                element.parent().find('input').removeClass('active');
                inputBox.addClass('active');
                scope.target = ctrl.instanceId;
                scope.$apply();
            })
            /*   .bind('blur', function () {
                inputBox.removeClass('active');
            });*/
   
            // code for focusOn from here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14833326/how-to-set-focus-on-input-field
            scope.$on('focusOn', function (e, name, iconClass) {
                console.log('focuson triggered', name, element[0]);
                if (name === 'focus' + ctrl.instanceId) {
                    console.log('focus now!!', element.find('input')[0]);
                    element.find('input')[0].focus();
                    inputBox.addClass('active');
                    scope.icon = iconClass;
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

function MainController($scope, focus) {
    $scope.focusTarget = 1; // last acitve input box --> sets first focus
    focus('focus' + $scope.focusTarget); // activate focus with-out class
}

function FocusFactory($rootScope, $timeout) {
    return function (name, iconClass) {
        $timeout(function () {
            $rootScope.$broadcast('focusOn', name, iconClass);
        });
    }
}
```

```css
.iconbar-icon {
  cursor: pointer;
}
.icon-placeholder {
  width: 16px;
  padding: 5px;
}
[iconbar] {
  border: 1px solid;
  padding: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
}
.active {
  border: 2px solid blue;
}
i {
  padding-right: 5px;
}
.icon-invisible {
  visibility: hidden;
}
/* spacer not working */

.icon-spacer::before,
.icon-blank::before {
  width: 1em;
  content: ' ';
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.4.0/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="demoApp" ng-controller="mainController">
  <div iconbar focus-target="{{focusTarget}}"> <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-bus"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-bug"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-beer"></i>

  </div>
  <!--{{focusTarget}}-->
  <icon-input target="focusTarget"></icon-input>
  <icon-input target="focusTarget"></icon-input>
</div>
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. While this is a nice implementation, I should have been more clearer in my question. I meant I wanted to append a symbol to the _data_ within the text field, not make an icon appear next to the text field. By symbol I mean characters like © (the copyright symbol). However I'm sure it wouldn't be too difficult to change your code accordingly, correct?

Comment: Ah, OK, then it's a bit wrong with my symbol before the input. That wasn't clear. But adding the symbol to the text field data is also possible with my code. It took a while to add because I had troubles with `ngModel` formatters / parsers (see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32150392/how-to-use-ngmodel-directives-formatter-parsers-in-a-custom-directive/32161879#32161879)). But now it is working. Here is an updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/awolf2904/d0y6gy9r/12/).

Comment: That is closer, but I was wanting the symbol to be appended to the right of the text in the input, not to the left. And I should have the ability to continue to append more and more symbols if I continue to click the toolbar icon. Sorry lol, but really appreciate your help.

Comment: Nevermind, I figured it out. I just changed the one line appending the symbol to "scope.inputText = tempString +  $sanitize(iconClass);" and that solved my problem. Thanks!